# Using JQuery to bind to click events in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, bind

I am attempting to expand on the examples from [MattHidinger.com](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx) to add pop up dialogs to an MVC site.

Using the code from his site...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                modal: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 350
            })
                .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and an Html.ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete via actionlink", "Delete", "CostModel"
, new { id = item.HighlightReportID }
, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "dialog", data_dialog_title =
 string.Format("Delete {0}", item.DisplayIdentifier) })
```

I can render an anchor tag that, when clicked, opens a UI Dialog.

```
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="dialog" data-dialog-title="Delete report for Nov 12" href="/CostModel/Delete/162">Delete via actionlink</a>
```

But!

If I add an anchor tag manually to the page using the same identifying structures, it fails.

```
<a class="openDialog" data_dialog_id="dialog" data_dialog_title="Delete report for Nov 12" href="/CostModel/Delete/162">Delete via manual anchor tag</a>
```

Is there a reason why MVC generated Anchor tags would work, versus manually created tags.

**Caveat**.  Obviously I would not be manually adding tags to a page in MVC.  I started by trying to use an ImageLink helper that generates an image inside the anchor tag and it failed too, so going back to first principals I tried the manual approach and was very confused when it failed!

### Edit 1

Here is the code from the page, note I have tried setting the data_dialog_id to be the same and different, adding both at the same time and individually, it makes no difference, only the ActionLink will be picked up by the JQuery.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete via actionlink", "Delete", "CostModel"
                    , new { id = item.HighlightReportID }
                    , new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "dialog1", data_dialog_title = string.Format("Delete {0}", item.DisplayIdentifier) })
<a class="openDialog"
                data_dialog_id="dialog2"
                data_dialog_title="@string.Format("Delete {0}", item.DisplayIdentifier)"
                href="/CostModel/Delete/@item.HighlightReportID">Delete via manual anchor tag</a>
```

and these are the two tags as rendered

```
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="dialog1" data-dialog-title="Delete report for Dec 12" href="/CostModel/Delete/212">Delete via actionlink</a>
<a class="openDialog" data_dialog_id="dialog2" data_dialog_title="Delete report for Dec 12" href="/CostModel/Delete/212">Delete via manual anchor tag</a>
```

As far as my eyes can see they are identical, and yet only the first one (dialog1) will be picked up by the jquery.

Comment: Try using `on` and delegate the click event to the document.

Comment: @Pow-Ian, while `.on` is indeed the recommended way to subscribe to events and `.live` is deprecated this won't change anything to the problem here and doesn't explain why the code works when using a helper.

Comment: Potentially it could explain it. I am thinking that the manually added links are in a different html context than the generated links. The ready event may not be firing with the manually added links in context. Personally I would try adding a click handler in a `<script>` tag in the view right after the manual tags are coded. Then you could ensure they are in the right context. The `on` event delegated to the document would catch it where the `live` may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason why hardcoding the markup would fail. All that the Html.ActionLink helper does is generate an HTML anchor which is the only thing visible to client side scripting. I guess that your problem lies somewhere else. For example you might have put different markup than what's generated by the helper. One thing that comes to mind is the `href` attribute which you have hardcoded to a non existent action. Don't forget that if you deploy your application in a virtual directory in IIS, if you hardcode the url (instead of using a helper) to `/CostModel/Delete/162` that might fail because the correct url is now `/myappname/CostModel/Delete/162`. That's one of the reasons why you should never be hardcoding urls in an ASP.NET MVC application.

You could use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome Developer toolbar in order to inspect your code and see potential problems. Also look in your console for possible errors.

Comment: Darin, thanks for answering the question on whether it _should_ work!  I've added more examples but will have to start picking it apart in chrome developer to see why it isn't.